# Why is property of user object in mongoose showing as undefined?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    nativeLanguage: {
        type: String, 
        default: "English"
    },
```

This route prints out the user object to the console.

```
router.get('/add', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const Users = await User.find({_id: req.params._id});
    console.log(req.user);
    res.render('add', {User});
    });
```

What I am trying to do is render specific properties of the user on the `add` page, to test that I am first trying to access them in the console. Unfortunately `User.nativeLanguage` comes up as undefined and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

`User` is the model, `Users` as you named it is the user record.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you export your model.

```
exports.User = UserSchema;
```

Then in your route you need.

```
var user = require('../userModel');

user.find({ _id: req.params._id }, (err, doc) => (
    if (!err && doc){
        res.render('add', { User: doc});
    }
))
```

Also consider using findOne instead of find if you plan to get only one record.